# new WorkboxPlugin({ TypeError: WorkboxPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, jhipster

**I am Building a production package of Jhipster application using gradlew -Pprod command but getting following error**

```
D:\My Project\other\beequote\webpack\webpack.prod.js:89
        new WorkboxPlugin({
        ^

TypeError: WorkboxPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\My Project\other\beequote\webpack\webpack.prod.js:89:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireConfig (D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:97:18)
    at D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:104:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:102:15)
    at yargs.parse (D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:171:41)
    at Object.Yargs.self.parse (D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:533:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\My Project\other\beequote\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:152:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
```

**Before getting above Error I was getting following error but after Upadate "workbox-webpack-plugin of with version 3.0.0-alpha.3 I solved following error using** [this solution](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6950)

```
Error: workbox-sw is needed by the service worker and could not be copied over to your new site. Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\projects\jhipster-app\build\www\workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.2.js'
    at Promise.all.then.catch (C:\projects\jhipster-app\node_modules\workbox-build\build\lib\utils\copy-workbox-sw.js:17:13)
    at <anonymous>
```

Please help me so solve this error

Comment: Please edit your question with JHipster version and details about what you have changed. Have you tried to reproduce on a fresh project generated by latest version?

Answer (score 3):

WorkboxWebpackPlugin in version 3.0 is broken into two parts to be used.

The way to use WorkboxWebpackPlugin is either

`new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({...})` 
for generating a fresh new Service worker

or

`new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({...})`
for injecting pre-cache file list in your own service worker.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#configuration